# Diagnose the exact cause of WAIT_ON_SYNC_STATISTICS_REFRESH

Tags: sql-server-2019, statistics, waits

We are currently facing query timeout issues with our online API .

The related request is an ad hoc select query referencing two tables.
In Redgate, we see that each time the request is blocked, it's due to "WAIT_ON_SYNC_STATISTICS_REFRESH".

I tried to match occurrence of blocking with ongoing statistic refresh using requests on `sys.stats` or `sys.dm_tran_locks` but I can't find any clear relations.

I can't find any updated statistic related to the request during the occurrence of blocking, neither I can manage to find CPU or I/O consumption issues.

I know we could try to use the asynchronous statistic update strategy on the database, but I would like to understand the reasons of the problem first.

Any idea would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Start by capturing the Profiler [Auto Stats Event Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/auto-stats-event-class) (or Extended Event) filtered on *EventSubClass* = 1:

> Statistics created/updated synchronously; **TextData** column indicates which statistics and whether they were created or updated